# Faulty file in use error

Tags: c#, winforms, io

This code is the first code in my `Form_Load` method:

```
DirectoryInfo dir =new DirectoryInfo("d:\\themes.thumb");

string[] animals = new string []
{
    "Snakes",
    "SnowyOwls",
    "Tigers",
    "TropicalFish",
    "WildBeauty",
    "Wolves"
};

foreach (FileInfo fil in dir.GetFiles())
{
    for(int ii=0;ii<animals.Length;ii++)
    {
        if (fil.Name.StartsWith(animals[ii]))
        {
        try
        {
            fil.Replace(fil.FullName,fil.FullName.Replace(fil.Name,"Animals-" + fil.Name));
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }
}
```

and I'm getting the following error whenever `if (fil.Name.StartsWith(animals[ii]))` is true:

> The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

What is wrong as I have not opened any files before this code?

Comment: as an idea: maybe dir.GetFiles() creates a lock on the file?

Comment: well I first thought of that but then I thought it must be really silly if just getting the file list put lock on them as its supposed to be used like this

Comment: Does this code really compile for you?  What are all those `private` scattered around?

Comment: What's up with all the `private` in the code? Does that even compile?

Comment: @nvoigt someone edited my question he must have add them there were no **private** in my code. I cleared them again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should seperate your reading logic from your update logic.

for example:

```
var replacements = dir.GetFiles()
                      .Where(file => animals.Any(animal => file.Name.StartsWith(animal)))
                      .Select(file => new 
                                     {
                                       OldFullName = file.FullName, 
                                       NewFullName = file.FullName.Replace(file.Name, "Animals-" + file.Name) 
                                     })
                      .ToList();

foreach (var replacement in replacements)
{
    File.Move(replacement.OldFullName, replacement.NewFullName);
}
```

Your replace logic has some subtle bugs (what happens with files that are in a folder called "Wolves" for example?) you may wan to work that out.

Comment: you mean that getting files locks it?

Comment: As your renaming of files actually *invalidates* the information in the array you got from `GetFiles`, I'll take a wild guess and say yes.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are misunderstanding how to use the `FileInfo.Replace` method.

```
fil.Replace(fil.FullName,fil.FullName.Replace(fil.Name,"Animals-" + fil.Name));
```

Here you are actually trying to overwrite `fil`'s contents with itself. That explains the error message.

You might want to read the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8a3t4ek5(v=vs.110).aspx) a bit more closely.

**EDIT:**
To be absolutely clear: `FileInfo.Replace` is not meant to be used to perform file **renames**.  It's meant to replace file **contents**.  To perform a rename, you use `FileInfo.MoveTo`.

Comment: yes. the replace works as rename whenever the destination file is the file itself

Comment: Oh my.  That's the worst way to do a rename, and causes the error message you encountered.  Please don't do that.

Comment: well what would you offer for renaming?

Comment: `fil.MoveTo(fil.FullName.Replace(fil.Name,"Animals-" + fil.Name);`

Answer (score 0):

Get LockHunter. It's a free tool which shows you which process is holding onto a particular file or folder. I found it really useful.
Microsoft Process Explorer is also free and can also find open handles (Ctrl+F) by name.

Comment: the program is great but I want to know where the error is. but the programs only shows that which program is using hte file